# Parse JSON with R

Tags: json, r

I am fairly new to R, but the more use it, the more I see how powerful it really is over SAS or SPSS.  Just one of the major benefits, as I see them, is the ability to get and analyze data from the web.  I imagine this is possible (and maybe even straightforward), but I am looking to parse JSON data that is publicly available on the web.  I am not a programmer by any stretch, so any help and instruction you can provide will be greatly appreciated.  Even if you point me to a basic working example, I probably can work through it.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

[RJSONIO](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJSONIO/index.html) from Omegahat is another package which provides facilities for reading and writing data in JSON format.

[rjson](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html) does not use S4/S3 methods and so is not readily extensible, but still useful. Unfortunately, it does not used vectorized operations and so is too slow for non-trivial data. Similarly, for reading JSON data into R, it is somewhat slow and so does not scale to large data, should this be an issue.

**Update** (new Package 2013-12-03):

[jsonlite](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html): This package is a fork of the `RJSONIO` package. It builds on the parser from `RJSONIO` but implements a different mapping between R objects and JSON strings. The C code in this package is mostly from the `RJSONIO` Package, the R code has been rewritten from scratch. In addition to drop-in replacements for `fromJSON` and `toJSON`, the package has functions to serialize objects. Furthermore, the package contains a lot of unit tests to make sure that all edge cases are encoded and decoded consistently for use with dynamic data in systems and applications.

Comment: I found [this comparison](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31702_9c22e3d1a0c44968a4a1f9656f1800ab.html) of rjson, RJSONIO, and jsonlite helpful

Comment: The comparison link above is dead.  Is [this](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31702_9c22e3d1a0c44968a4a1f9656f1800ab.html) the correct link?  (the difference is https)

Answer (score 73):

The [jsonlite](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) package is easy to use and tries to convert json into data frames.

Example:

```
library(jsonlite)

# url with some information about project in Andalussia
url <- 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges?order=desc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow'

# read url and convert to data.frame
document <- fromJSON(txt=url)
```

Comment: This was incredibly easy to use for what I needed. Thank you so much

Comment: document <- fromJSON(file = url); #but the request times out

Comment: Love this. Seems much better than the clutter created by rjson.

Comment: Unless the original json format is already flattened, `jsonlite` is more or less as useful as a fork to eat soup.

Answer (score 21):

Here is the missing example

```
library(rjson)
url <- 'http://someurl/data.json'
document <- fromJSON(file=url, method='C')
```

Comment: this worked for me but you don't want to pass a string for the file variable name as shown.

Answer (score 5):

The function fromJSON() in RJSONIO, rjson and jsonlite don't return a simple 2D data.frame for complex nested json objects.

To overcome this you can use **tidyjson**. It takes in a json and always returns a data.frame. It is currently not availble in CRAN, you can get it here: https://github.com/sailthru/tidyjson

**Update:**  tidyjson is now available in cran, you can install it directly using `install.packages("tidyjson")`

Answer (score 2):

For the record, rjson and RJSONIO do change the file type, but they don't really parse per se. For instance, I receive ugly MongoDB data in JSON format, convert it with rjson or RJSONIO, then use unlist and tons of manual correction to actually parse it into a usable matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code using RJSONIO in console

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)


json_file = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isrini/SI_IS607/master/books.json")

json_file2 = RJSONIO::fromJSON(json_file)

head(json_file2)
```