# Cleaning data with R

Tags: json, r

I am new to R, but I am trying to manipulate data in a JSON format. I can get the data into by using Rstudio's import function, but I have having trouble converting it into a table. the string read like this.

```
'type': 'business',
'business_id': (encrypted business id),
'name': (business name),
'neighborhoods': [(hood names)],
'full_address': (localized address),
```

There are close 4,000 observations. how do i get rid of 'type', 'business_id', etc? I would like to have the variables labeled like a table.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the packages that deal with `JSON`? Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r).  Did you look online for ways to load `JSON` into `R`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at rjson package -> toJSON() function
More info at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/rjson.pdf