# parsing text in R

Tags: json, r, parsing, text

I have to parse a third party supplied text that is in following format:

`"{ \"responseObjects\" : [ { \"isCorrect\" : \"F\" , \"displayText\" : \"8,11\" , \"displayOrder\" : 1} , { \"isCorrect\" : \"F\" , \"displayText\" : \"9,13\" , \"displayOrder\" : 2} , { \"isCorrect\" : \"T\" , \"displayText\" : \"'11, 13\" , \"displayOrder\" : 3} , { \"isCorrect\" : \"F\" , \"displayText\" : \"'12,15\" , \"displayOrder\" : 4}] , \"stem\" : { \"displayText\" : \"Extend the numerical pattern: 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, ____, ____\"}}"`

the \ are escape characters. The entire text above is a cell in a dataframe (read from
a database)

I need to grab the text that comes after "stem", i.e., every entry will have the key word "stem" : { "display test" : "actual text"} } any suggestions on how I can grab the "actual text" in the sentence. (all other text are not relevant to the app) Thank you very much.

Comment: same text as above, without the \ escape character

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON with R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r)

Comment: Parse the string using a JSON parser, and then extract the fields from the resulting object.

Comment: Thanks got it! JSON parser works.