# Extracting columns from "JSON" file

Tags: regex, r

I have some string which is similar to JSON file:

```
string <- "{'text': u'@RobertTekieli @Czerniakowianka @1234Mania mysle, ze nie weszlabym do zadnego wiezienia bez straznikow', 'created_at': u'Tue May 20 08:16:55 +0000 2014'}"
```

I want to extract two strings -which are after `text` and `created_at`

```
@RobertTekieli @Czerniakowianka @1234Mania mysle, ze nie weszlabym do zadnego wiezienia bez straznikow
```

and

```
Tue May 20 08:16:55 +0000 2014
```

I want to do it with regex not with `fromJSON` function or something like that. But actually I don't know how. Any suggestion?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r

Comment: Parsing JSON string with regex can be very painful. What is the reason that you don't want to use built-in functions ?

Comment: That's still not valid JSON data. You really should try to get valid input. It will make life easier for you in the long run.

Comment: I know, that's why I want to treat it like normal string. `stri_extract_all_regex(wiadomosc, "\\{'text': u'.*")` gives me the whole text, how can I "say" in regex language that I want to end before 'created_at"? It would bu satisfing too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=text':\su')[^']+|(?<=created_at':\su')[^']+
```

You can try this .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/27

Answer (score 2):

Use `\K` to discard the previously matched characters from printing at the final. [`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.

```
> string <- "{'text': u'@RobertTekieli @Czerniakowianka @1234Mania mysle, ze nie weszlabym do zadnego wiezienia bez straznikow', 'created_at': u'Tue May 20 08:16:55 +0000 2014'}"
> m <- gregexpr("'(?:text|created_at)':\\s+u'\\K[^']*", string, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(string, m)
[[1]]
[1] "@RobertTekieli @Czerniakowianka @1234Mania mysle, ze nie weszlabym do zadnego wiezienia bez straznikow"
[2] "Tue May 20 08:16:55 +0000 2014"
```

**OR**

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract_all(string, perl("'(?:text|created_at)':\\s+u'\\K[^']*"))[[1]]
[1] "@RobertTekieli @Czerniakowianka @1234Mania mysle, ze nie weszlabym do zadnego wiezienia bez straznikow"
[2] "Tue May 20 08:16:55 +0000 2014"
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/vM2vZ5/3)

Comment: You are a true Regex ninja, @AvinasRaj. I would go with something like https://www.regex101.com/r/vM2vZ5/1 since `' u'` part is always fixed as well and wouldn't need a regex lookup.