# Read JSONs in R to data.frame

Tags: json, r

I have list of JSON values (actually it's a text file where every line is one JSON object). Like this:

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "john", "age": 18, "education": "master" }
{ "id": 2, "name": "jack", "job": "clerk" }
...
```

Some of the values can be missing (e.g. first item doesn't have "job" value and second item doesn't have "education" and "age").

I need to create data frame in R and fill all missing column values as NAs (if field with unique name exists in at least one row). How to achieve this easier?

What I already done - I installed "rjson" package and parsed these lines to R lists. Let's assume that lines variable is a character vector of lines.

```
library(rjson)
lines <- // initialize "lines" var here
jsons <- sapply(lines, fromJSON)
```

"jsons" variable became "list of lists" (every JSON object is converted to list in R terminology). How to convert it to data.frame?

I want to see the following data frame for the example I provided:

```
"id" | "name" | "age" | "education" | "job"
-------------------------------------------
1    | "john" |  18   |  "master"   |   NA
2    | "jack  |  NA   |     NA      | "clerk"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `plyr` you can use `rbind.fill` to add the NAs for you

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(sapply(jsons, data.frame), jsons)

#   id name age education   job
# 1  1 john  18    master  <NA>
# 2  2 jack  NA      <NA> clerk
```

or from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(jsons, fill=T)
```

and `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(sapply(jsons, data.frame))
```

Comment: There is one issue, though. If any of the field in JSON has explicit NULL value, this code isn't working with error message "arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0"

Comment: @pkozlov - again, I'll point out that `jsonlite` deals with this issue with robust checking, and will just read `null` as final `NA` values in a data.frame.

Answer (score 3):

Future me, correcting past me's mistakes. It would make more sense to use `jsonlite`'s `stream_in`

```
stream_in(txtfile)

# To test on `txt` from below, try:
# stream_in(textConnection(txt))

# Found 2 records...
# Imported 2 records. Simplifying...
#  id name age education   job
#1 NA john  18    master  <NA>
#2  2 jack  NA      <NA> clerk
```

---

Use the `jsonlite` package's `fromJSON` function, after making a few inline edits to your original text data (I've also edited the first piece of `id` data to include an explicit `null` value, to show that it deals with this):

```
fromJSON(paste0("[", gsub("}\n", "},\n", txt), "]"))
#  id name age education   job
#1 NA john  18    master  <NA>
#2  2 jack  NA      <NA> clerk
```

All I did was add a little formatting to wrap all the JSON lines together in `[` and `]` and add a comma at the end of each closing `}` - resulting in an output like the below which can be processed all at once by `jsonlite::fromJSON`:

```
[{"1":"one"},{"2":"two"}]
```

Where `txt` was your lines of data as presented, with a `null` in the `id` variable:

```
txt <- "{ \"id\": null, \"name\": \"john\", \"age\": 18, \"education\": \"master\" }
{ \"id\": 2, \"name\": \"jack\", \"job\": \"clerk\" }"
```

Comment: I don't like this option. The reason why this text file has one JSON object per line is that file can be very big - and reading it as one big JSON array can be memory- and time consuming.

It's better to process each line independently, can be even done in parallel, I think.

Thank you for the response anyway.

Comment: @pkozlov - if you're using `sapply` to loop over each line in R, you'll have to load whatever part you are operating on into R's memory anyway. There's nothing stopping you from `scan`ning in 10 thousand lines at a time, and then processing/parallel processing using this method. Also, jsonlite is better scaled for large data as per: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2062865/496803