# Importing Data into R from Microsoft Outlook Body of Email

Tags: r, email, outlook

I have a no-reply email that gets sent to me every hour with a spreadsheet with alerts notifying me when performance is down. The table looks as follows:

[image]

Is it possible to call the body of this email from Microsoft Outlook into R? I basically want to call out this table (which changes every hour). So currently I think the best way to do it is by calling the most recent email with the name of the subject because the subject never changes. From there I want to manipulate what I need in R, I just don't know how to make the connection from the body of a Microsoft Outlook email into R.

Any help would be great and I know this is kind of a strange question.

Thanks!

Comment: How many of these already answered questions have you read and attempted http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+outlook?

Comment: why involve outlook at all? mailboxes can be "virtual" and simply be an application that accepts the mail, and there's plenty of other utilities can grab/check mailboxes and do stuff automatically.

Comment: @PierreLafortune I have looked through that and there is not an answer to my question in those options

Comment: I think you can use a command line email client, make a scheduled system call and scrape the html email the way you prefer to do it for web pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can hit the Outlook Rest API directly from R and import the data into a dataframe using a variety of libraries.

Outlook Rest API Reference for Mail:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations

Stack Overflow answer for parsing Json:
[Parse JSON with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r)

Comment: Sample R code illustrating how to hit the Outlook REST API from R would be helpful.

Comment: This does not work if you your Outlook is using Microsoft Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a loop with the `library(tm.plugin.mail)` or a function to import it like a dataframe