# Adding a character before every specific character in each line in R

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table, data-science

I have a .csv, file unfortunately one of the columns contains a dictionary  that has commas in it , for example:

```
{"name": "Umbulharjo", "type": "Kecamatan", "level": "3", "region1": "Yogyakarta", "region2": "Yogyakarta", "region3": "Umbulharjo", "postcode": "55161"}
```

How can i put a " before every { and after every } in R? then i can set " as quote when i am using read.csv or read.csv2 or read.table

Comment: Look for search and replace in R using regex and gsub().

Comment: this link may prove useful to you.

Comment: You can simply use `paste`

Comment: `rl <- readLines('test.csv'); rl <- gsub('(?={)|(?<=})', '\'', rl, perl = TRUE); read.csv(text = rl, quote = '\'')` maybe

Comment: @RanchiRhino which link?

Comment: Sorry i missed the paste http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/in-r-how-do-i-replace-text-within-a-string

Comment: https://susanejohnston.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/find-and-replace-in-r-part-2-how-to-recode-many-values-simultaneously/

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks to be JSON-ish.  If you're doing a lot of JSON stuff, I suggest using a [library that understands JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r).

Comment: NO it is not JSON at all only one columns has this structure out of 45 .

Answer (score 0):

```
paste('{"name": "Umbulharjo", "type": "Kecamatan", "level": "3", "region1": "Yogyakarta", "region2": "Yogyakarta", "region3": "Umbulharjo", "postcode": "55161"}', '')
#[1] "{\"name\": \"Umbulharjo\", \"type\": \"Kecamatan\", \"level\": \"3\", \"region1\": \"Yogyakarta\", \"region2\": \"Yogyakarta\", \"region3\": \"Umbulharjo\", \"postcode\": \"55161\"} "
```

Comment: 2.5 million rows how can i paste?

Comment: `paste` is vectorised.