# How import log file system json file in R?

Tags: json, r

I'm trying to import a data file of log-file system. The data are collected in json and are download in txt. Here an example of a string:

> { "index" : {}} { "time": 1463687400,"_dominio": "SAG","_ambiente":
>   "PROD", "numChars": 12029395, "numLogs": 598, "numLines": 89597,
>   "numWords": 1025832, "numDistinctWords": 1356 }

How I can parse this file in R?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fromJSON` from `jsonlite`

```
 library(jsonlite)
 fromJSON(str1)
```

Comment: You meant `fromJSON` right? OP is looking to import.