# Converting JSON data into data.frame

Tags: json, r

How can I convert this  kind of JSON data to data.frame:

```
library("rjson")
fromJSON("[{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]")
```

> Error in fromJSON("[{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]") : 
>     unexpected character "'"; expecting opening string quote (") for key value
>   when I used fromJSON() I got this:unexpected character "'"; expecting opening string quote (") for key value

Comment: look into the package called `jsonlite`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r)

Comment: a `vector` is probably not what you want for this data, you probably want a `data.frame`. Also, you'll need to replace the single-quotes with doubles, and the double-quotes with singles ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14355655/5977215) )

Comment: this is last error what I got:  fromJSON("[{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]")
Error in fromJSON("[{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]") : 
  unexpected character "'"; expecting opening string quote (") for key value

Answer (score 3):

For JSON to be valid it needs double-quotes inside the JSON string (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14355655/5977215) for reference). Therefore, you also need single-quotes surrounding it to make it a valid string in R.

You can swap your single and double quotes by using that awesome piece of regex supplied by r2evans

```
## this is your invalid string
js <- "[{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]"

## convert it to a valid string
js <- gsub("QUUX", "'", gsub("'", '"', gsub('"', "QUUX", js)))
```

Or by making use of the `?chartr` function (thanks to thelatemail)

```
js <- chartr("\'\"","\"\'",js)
```

Then most JSON parsing libraries should work, for example,

Using **jsonlite** will give you a **data.frame**

```
df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(js)

df
#     id    name
#1    18   Drama
#2    28  Action
#3 10749 Romance
```

And using **rjson** will give you a **list**

```
rjson::fromJSON(js)

[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] 18

[[1]]$name
[1] "Drama"


[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[1] 28

[[2]]$name
[1] "Action"


[[3]]
[[3]]$id
[1] 10749

[[3]]$name
[1] "Romance"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I understood what you mean. But  my JSON data is written  with double quotes , and i don't know how to read this

Comment: `gsub("QUUX", "'", gsub("'", '"', gsub('"', "QUUX", x)))`?

Comment: @AzizIlyosov  Also, how is your JSON generated?

Comment: I downloaded this Data from Internet and I don't know how is that generated

Comment: @AzizIlyosov - see my edit for how to use r2evans' regex

Comment: sorry SymbolixAU what I need is data.frame as you told me ;) I am new in this field

Comment: @AzizIlyosov - I've updated my answer again to make it clearer

Comment: No need for the double regex - just use `chartr` - `fromJSON(chartr("\'\"","\"\'",js))`