# Storing lists in csv to access in r

Tags: python, r, list, csv

I've been storing my data in a structure that looks like this:

```
dictionary = {'name': 'Jeff', 'state': 'CA', finish_times: [17.34, 12.23]}
```

When I write it to csv, I only want this data to take up one row, so like:

```
 Name   State   Finish_Times
'Jeff'  'CA'   [17.34, 12.23]
```

And I've been able to write the data to a csv exactly like that. The problem is I can't manipulate the list in R. Is there a way to convert the list to a format manageable by R? or will I have to restructure my data?

EDIT: Thanks for all the responses, I've tried using JSON, but I think I'm just gonna manipulate my scraped data within python. That way I can correctly interpret the lists and dictionaries I'm making.

Comment: are you familiar with pandas?

Comment: There **is no list**. A csv is a series of bytes. There is a valid *python list literal* represented in those bytes, but R doesn't know or care. The *correct* solution would be to use some sort of common serialization format. One option would be to use JSON,  popular text-based serialization format.

Comment: According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r there are a couple of JSON libraries available for R. The Python standard library comes with the `json` module.I'm not sure *what* sort of R container a JSON object will be deserialized into (Python `dict` objects will be serialized into JSON objects, note, JSON looks a lot like Python literals, indeed, most valid JSON is a valid Python literal (one exception, JSON uses `null` instead of `None`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jsonlite library`

you can convert a `json` format to `data frame` like this way:

```
library(jsonlite)
json <-
'[
  {"Name" : "Mario", "Age" : 32, "Occupation" : "Plumber"}, 
  {"Name" : "Peach", "Age" : 21, "Occupation" : "Princess"},
  {},
  {"Name" : "Bowser", "Occupation" : "Koopa"}
]'
mydf <- fromJSON(json)
mydf
```

this will give you a data frame like this:

```
   Name   Age  Occupation
1  Mario  32    Plumber
2  Peach  21   Princess
3   <NA>  NA       <NA>
4 Bowser  NA      Koopa
```

Once you have the `data frame` you can save it to `csv`

```
write.csv(mydf,"myfile.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```

here is a small [tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html)