# How to extract characters after a match from a string in r?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a variable in a data frame that contains raw json text. Some observations have a set 14 digit number that I want to extract and some don't. If the observation has the information it is under this format:

**{"blur": "10010010010010"**

I want to extract the 14 digits after **{"blur": "** if there is a match for this left-hand side part of the string. I tried str_extract but my regex syntax is not the best, any suggestions here?

Comment: What about using a JSON parser? [Parse JSON with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r)

Comment: Why not just use a positive lookbehind ? `(?<=\{"blur": ")(\d+)` ?

Comment: use `dput(head(R_object))` to display the R object. The JSON text you posted looks like the "blur" and the number are separate, so how you entered the file into R may affect what is the correct pattern to use.

Answer (score 1):

If it's fully formed JSON you could use a JSON parser but assuming

- it's just fragments as shown in the question or it is fully formed and you prefer to use regular expressions anyways
- each input has 0 or 1 occurrences of the digit string
- if 0 occurrences then use `NA`

then try this.

The second argument to `strapply` is the regular expression.  It returns the portion matched to the capture group, i.e. the part of the regular expression within parentheses.  The `empty=NA` argument tells it what to return if no occurrences are found.

```
library(gsubfn)
s <- c('{"blur": "10010010010010"', 'abc') # test input

strapply(s, '{"blur": "(\\d+)"', empty = NA, simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "10010010010010" NA
```