# Find and extract JSON data from within character string in R

Tags: r, json

I am after a way (preferably an existing function) that can locate legitimate JSON data *within* a character string

#### What I know already

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r), `jsonlite::fromJSON()` can parse JSON, like so:

```
library(jsonlite)

json_glob_1 <- "{ \"age\": 22}"
json_glob_2 <- "{ \"name\":\"John\" }"

fromJSON(json_glob_1)
# $age
# [1] 22

fromJSON(json_glob_2)
# $name
# [1] "John"
```

#### What I do not know

Is there a function that can accept an impure string and return the JSON glob(s) from within that string; e.g.

```
messy_string_with_json <- paste0("lsdfjksdlfjk dkfjsldfkjs fkjsdf", 
                                               json_glob_1, 
                                               "slkdfjlskdfj sfkdjflskdjf sdfk", 
                                               json_glob_2, 
                                               "32345jlskdfj")

find_JSON(messy_string_with_json)
[[1]]
[1] "{ \"age\": 22}" 
[2] "{ \"name\":\"John\" }"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if one exists out-the-box, but you can write one.

Here I'm using regex to [find all values between braces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8613332/5977215)

Then calling `jsonlite::validate` on the results to see if it's valid or not.

```r
library(jsonlite)

json_glob_1 <- "{ \"age\": 22}"
json_glob_2 <- "{ \"name\":\"John\" }"

x <- paste0(
    "lsdfjksdlfjk dkfjsldfkjs fkjsdf"
    , json_glob_1
    , "slkdfjlskdfj sfkdjflskdjf sdfk"
    , json_glob_2
    , "32345jlskdfj"
    )


## try and find values between braces
possible <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?=\\{).*?(?<=\\})", x, perl=T))[[1]]

## then try and valide them as JSON
sapply( possible, jsonlite::validate )

#     { "age": 22} { "name":"John" } 
#             TRUE              TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to work on small JSON globs, but consider `x <- paste0(
  "lsdfjksdlfjk dkfjsldfkjs fkjsdf"
  , toJSON(iris)
  , "slkdfjlskdfj sfkdjflskdjf sdfk"
  , json_glob_2
  , "32345jlskdfj"
)`; it will return 151 globs instead of just 2

Comment: You can get the whole array with `possible <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?=\\[).*?(?<=\\])", x, perl=T))[[1]]`